# Hash function: Is there a way to optimize my code further?

Tags: c++, hash

[image]

Above is the hash function.

I wrote the code below. I am not sure if I can use another clever way to make this more efficient. I am using the understanding that I do not need to do the mod at all since unsigned int takes care of that through overflow.

```
int myHash(string s)
{
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    long long int multiplier = 1;
    for(int i = s.size()-1;i>-1;i--)
    {
        hash += (multiplier * s[i]);
        multiplier *= 31;
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: if you are linking to an actual image, link to the image, not a gallery

Comment: Perhaps code review is a better forum for this.

Comment: Note that unsigned int is not guaranteed to be exactly 32 bits wide (although it often is that wide).  If you want to rely on the overflow behavior of a 32-bit unsigned variable, your code will be more portable if you use type uint32_t instead (via #include <cstdint>) rather than unsigned int.

Comment: I would say that the answer is this: We have no idea. It depends on your compiler, the processor it compiles for, the data you hash, the implementation of std::string, and perhaps other things. The only way to know is to _measure_. (But I agree with N00byEdge about `const string &s`.)

Comment: The answer also would depend on your criterion for optimisation.  Minimising size of the executable file or memory usage can be very different from minimising number of CPU cycles or time based measures.   Worry more about getting the function behaving correctly (i.e. reliably producing the expected output for all feasible inputs).   Then test (profile, benchmark, etc) to gather evidence about how well it performs. ONLY then worry about "optimisation".   At present (assuming your implementation, as shown, works as intended) all you're doing is premature optimisation.

Comment: *at least* make everything unsigned (signed integers can cause overflow). And I don't see the need for the backward loop. The loop index can be made unsigned as well : `for(unsigned int i = s.size(); i-- > 0;) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using `long long` for multiplier. At least if you don't know 100% that your processor does 64-bit multiplies in the same amount of time as a 32-bit multiply. Really modern top of the range processors probably do, older & smaller processors almost certainly take longer to do 64-bit mul operations than 32-bit ones.

Multiplying by 31 can actually be quite fast even on processors that aren't good at multiplying, because `x *= 31` can be converted to `x = x * 32 - x;` or `x = (x << 5) - x;` - in fact it may be worth trying that [if you haven't compiled the code to assembler and seen that the compiler already does that].

Beyond that, it would be processor or compiler-specific optimisations that comes to mind. Loop unrolling for example. Or using inline assembler or intrinsics to make use of vector instructions (subject to availability for different processor architectures and different generations). Modern compilers like recent versions of gcc or clang will probably vectorize this code, subject to being given the "right" options.

As with all optimisation projects, measure the time, using a representative workload, keep records of what you changed. Look at the generated code, try to figure out if there's a better way to do it. And don't lose track of the fact that it's the OVERALL program's performance that matter. If you spend 80% of the time in this function, by all means, optimize the heck out of it. If you spend 20% of the time, optimize it a bit, if you spend 2% of the time in it, unless there's OBVIOUS things you can do to improve it, it's not going to give you much. I've seen the results of people writing code to save a few clock-cycles in some code that takes several million cycles in the loop two lines further on. And using bit-fiddling tricks to save 2 bytes in something that takes half a megabyte. It just creates mess, not really worth doing.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could make the argument not have to copy the string for the function call, make s `const string &s` instead, or use `std::string_view` if you happen to be using C++17. Otherwise it looks fast the the point where you should leave the rest to the compiler. Try making it optimize with `-O2` or your compilers equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this by saying it's probably not worth doing -- it's unlikely that your hash function is going to be the bottleneck in your program, so making the hash function more elaborate in an attempt to make it more efficient will probably just make it harder to understand and maintain while not making your program measurably faster.  So don't do this unless you've actually determined that your program spends a significant percentage of its time computing string hashes, and make sure you have a good benchmark routine that you can run "before" and "after" this change to verify that it actually did speed things up significantly, otherwise you might just be chasing rainbows.

That said, one potential way to hash long strings more quickly would be to process the string a word at a time rather than a character at a time, something like this:

```
unsigned int aSlightlyFasterHash(const string & s)
{
   const unsigned int numWordsInString      = s.size()/sizeof(unsigned int);
   const unsigned int numExtraBytesInString = s.size()%sizeof(unsigned int);

   // Compute the bulk of the hash by reading the string a word at a time
   unsigned int hash = 0;
   const unsigned int * iptr = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned int *>(s.c_str());
   for (unsigned int i=0; i<numWordsInString; i++)
   {
      hash += *iptr;
      iptr++;
   }

   // Then any "leftover" bytes at the end we will mix in to the hash the old way
   const unsigned char * cptr = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(iptr);
   unsigned int multiplier = 1;
   for(unsigned int i=0; i<numExtraBytesInString; i++)
   {
       hash += (multiplier * *cptr);
       cptr++;
       multiplier *= 31;
   }
   return hash;
}
```

Note that the above function will return different hash values than the hash function you provided.

That cuts down on the number of loop iterations by a factor of four; of course it's likely that the execution of the function is limited by RAM bandwidth rather than CPU cycles anyway, so do be too surprised if this doesn't go noticeably faster on a modern CPU.  If RAM bandwidth is indeed the bottleneck, then there's not too much you can do about it, since you have to read the contents of the string in order to compute a hash code for the string; there's no getting around that (except perhaps by precomputing the hash code in advance and storing it somewhere, but that only works if you know all the strings you are going to use in advance).

Comment: That would probably crash on some processors if `str` is not nicely aligned. And of course, won't actually give the same value - that may not really matter so much.

Comment: Agreed -- I'm assuming that the pointer returned by c_str() will be word-aligned; I'm not sure if that is a 100% valid assumption or not.

Comment: The C++ spec doesn't guarantee any alignment for the content inside a `std::string` (and it gets even worse if, for some reason, the input is `char *` instead).

Comment: I suppose the next thing to do would be to add more code to detect a misaligned c_str() pointer and read the first 1-3 bytes individually in that case -- but for the sake of my sanity I'm going to skip that part here.  :)